# Can I reproduce a trademarked logo in my blog?

Tags: trademark, fair-use

I have a blog about marketing. I am writing a new post where I talk about different Apple logos. Can I make a screen shot from Apple website and include that image in my blog? I just want to illustrate my text and help the reader follow what I am explaining.

Comment: Which country(ies) are you writing and hosting your blog in?

Comment: @Andrew: I am in Spain now. But does it matter? My blog is in English and most of my readers are in US.

Comment: It matters because Fair Use laws differ in different jurisdictions. It doesn't matter where your readers are; it matters where you are and (possibly) where your servers are located.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You only ask if you can. Yes, you can.

I'm assuming your question is more about if you violate any trademarks. In which case what you are doing sounds like it will fit into common exceptions to copyright law viz free speech and criticism.

The worst that will likely happen is you get a cease and desist letter.